# jaro-winkler with two conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

i have some problem when using jaro winkler in oracle. basically when compare similarity just write utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity('string 1','string 2'). how if i want to compare two data string, for example last name and birthdate.

i have data : 'Alex' and his birthdate '01-Feb-1990' and i want to compare with my record on database employee.last_name and employee.birthdate

how to write in oracle query using utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity() function?

thanks for your help

Comment: What is it that you want to be returned and why?  Comparing two dates based on string similarity doesn't strike me as being particularly reasonable.  To the extent that string similarity makes sense at all, you'd need to figure out how combining attributes makes sense in your environment.  Perhaps you want to average the two string similarities.  Perhaps you want to weight one of the attributes more heavily.  Perhaps you want something else.

Comment: i want to know the similarity two data that i want to compare. for example, i compare employee 'Alex' with birthdate '01-Feb-1990' with similarity name >80 that have record in other table

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a `name` and a `birth_date` column in your table and that you have a `name` and a `birth_date` that you want to look for matches in the table.  If Jaro-Winkler says that the name has a similarity of 80 and the birth date has a similarity of 40 (assuming it makes sense for some reason to do a string similarity comparison between two dates), what do you want to see returned?  In some cases, you might do a straight average of 60.  In others you might take the lower of the two scores of 40.  In others, you might do a weighted average.

Comment: Presume I was born on 24-MAR-2005. How "much" is that date similar to Alex' birthdate (01-FEB-1990)? What to compare? 24 vs. 01? Not similar. MAR vs. FEB? Not similar. 2005 vs. 1990? Not similar. Both dates were **thursdays** - VERY similar, but I'm not sure you're talking about that. Could you edit the question and provide some more sample data. We know all about Alex, but - post some more rows and explain what you're comparing with what.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the trick: CROSS JOIN whatever "values" you have with the rows in the existing table, call utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity() at every row, and filter out using WHERE.  Eg (using the OEHR_EMPLOYEES table)

```
select 
  first_name, fn_
, UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity( first_name, fn_ ) AS jws1
, hire_date,  dt_
, UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity( hire_date, dt_ ) AS jws2
from (
  ( select first_name, hire_date from oehr_employees )
  cross join 
  ( select  'Alex' fn_, date '1990-02-01' dt_ from dual ) -- your 2 "strings"
)
fetch first 10 rows only ;

-- result
FIRST_NAME  FN_  JWS1   HIRE_DATE   DT_         JWS2
Steven      Alex 47     10/30/2007  02/01/1990  62
Neena       Alex 48     02/03/2010  02/01/1990  85
Lex         Alex 72     05/28/2013  02/01/1990  66
Alexander   Alex 88     05/18/2010  02/01/1990  77
Bruce       Alex 0      10/03/2011  02/01/1990  65
David       Alex 0      11/07/2017  02/01/1990  67
Valli       Alex 48     06/20/2018  02/01/1990  73
Diana       Alex 0      06/22/2019  02/01/1990  73
Nancy       Alex 0      12/30/2014  02/01/1990  75
Daniel      Alex 47     12/29/2014  02/01/1990  65
```

If this is (kind-of) the result you're after,
just add a WHERE clause, eg

```
select 
  first_name, fn_, UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(first_name, fn_) AS jws1
, hire_date,  dt_, UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(hire_date, dt_) AS jws2
from (
  ( select first_name, hire_date from oehr_employees )
  cross join 
  ( select  'Alex' fn_, date '1990-02-01' dt_ from dual )
) 
where 
  UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(first_name, fn_) > 75 -- jws1
  and 
  UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(hire_date, dt_) > 75 -- jws2
;
```

OR (using "subquery factoring" / a CTE)

```
with T as (
  select 
    first_name, fn_, UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(first_name, fn_) AS jws1
  , hire_date,  dt_, UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(hire_date, dt_) AS jws2
  from (
    ( select first_name, hire_date from oehr_employees )
    cross join 
    ( select  'Alex' fn_, date '1990-02-01' dt_ from dual )
  )
)
select * 
from T
where jws1 > 75 and jws2 > 75 ;
```

If you want to compare 'Alex' to LAST_NAME in your existing table, just replace all the instances of 'first_name' by LAST_NAME (in the above queries).